# value which should match only numbers, dots and commas

Tags: java, regex

I have a regex:

```
"(\\d+\\.\\,?)+"
```

And the value:

```
3.053,500
```

But my regex pattern does not match it.
I want to have a pattern which validates numbers, dots and commas.
For exmaple values which are valid:

```
1
12
1,2
1.2
1,23,456
1,23.456
1.234,567
etc.
```

Comment: Try `s.matches("\\d+(?:[.,]\\d+)*")`, see [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/SDeijt/1).

Comment: In your pattern, the comma is optional but the `.` is not optional, so the string would have to end in `.` or `.,`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you Wiktor, that works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `(\d+\.\,?)+` regex matches 1 or more repetitions of 1+ digits, a dot, and an opional `,`. It means the strings must end with a dot. `3.053,500` does not end with a dot.

You may use

```
s.matches("\\d+(?:[.,]\\d+)*")
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/SDeijt/1)

Note that the `^` and `$` anchors are not necessary in Java's `.matches()` method as the match is anchored to the start/end of the string automatically. At regex101.com, the anchors are meant to match start/end of the line (since the demo is run against a multiline string).

**Pattern details**

- `\d+` - 1+ digits
- `(?:` - start of a non-capturing group:

  - `[.,]` - a dot or `,`
  - `\d+` - 1+ digits
- `)*` - 0 or more repetitions.